# If $X$ is a topological space, and $U\cap X_1$ and $V\cap X_2$ are relatively open, is $(U\cap X_1)\cup(V\cap X_2)$ open in $X_1\cup X_2$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space, and let $U$ and $V$ be open in $X$, so that $U\cap X_1$ and $V\cap X_2$ are relatively open subsets of some subsets $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I feel like it is *not* the case that $(U\cap X_1)\cup(V\cap X_2)$ is relatively open in $X_1\cup X_2$, but I'm having a hard time drawing a counterexample. Am I correct in my hunch, and is there a counterexample to verify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hunch is correct: consider the real numbers as $X$, $X_1=[0,1)$, and $X_2=[-2,2]$. Then $[0,1/2)$ is open in $X_1$ and $[-2,-1/2)$ is open in $X_2$, but $[-2,-1/2)\cup[0,1/2)$ is not open in $X_1\cup X_2$.

More generally, if $X_2$ has a proper open subset that contains $X_1$ and $X_1$ is not open in $X$, then my example can be modified appropriately to resolve the question.